# Formatting of a web page messed up when using proxy

Tags: macos, network, firefox, proxy, formatting

***Background***

For academic purposes I have to use an *university proxy* from my home in order to access some contents online available only with this method (PUBMED, a medical research database).

I have configured Firefox to connect through this proxy as explained in my faculty website.

***The problem***

However when accessing PUBMED I notice the proxy is working properly regarding the contents, meaning I can access contents usually unavailable without the proxy, but at the same time there are *errors in how the page is formatted*.

Everything happens to be in column in the left side of the screen.

I tried to disable all addons I had, but did not work.

Comment: I presume it all works correctly when using Firefox on campus? Do you need to go through a VPN first? (I know I did for my uni)

Comment: Yes, it works correctly when using Firefox on campus. No I just need to configure how FF connects to the web by "automatic configuration": http://proxy.cad.univpm.it/proxy.pac